How to convert photo to relief?
Just curious if anyone has recommendations for using Blender and maybe add-ons to make height map from a shaded photo, so I can take a picture of a relief carving and reproduce it for 3D printing.

I think there might be AI models capable of generating height/depth maps. I think you could use Stable Diffusion with ComfyUI to do that. It requires some time to set up and a decent GPU though. If we are talking about doing it in Blender, it's just good old modelling, but that's a whole lot of work. I would go with AI. Maybe if you already had a height map generated by AI, somebody could help you use it to make the geometry. That part is quite straight forward though - just a dense plane and displacement modifier.

If you have access to real relief, you could also take many photos of it and use photogrammetry to make a 3d model of it. Have a look at Meshroom. It's free and open source. There is commercial software like Agisoft Metashape or Reality Capture that may be more mature, but they might be very expensive. Not sure, but Reality Capture might have a free version, you could look into that, if Meshroom doesn't work for you for some reason.

Ah, thank you, that might work...

ComfyUI's ControlNet Auxiliary Preprocessors Depth Anything2 seems to work Well... Somewhat. It might be amazing for regular surface displacement maps.
